# Pull Docker image from Docker Hub and build it in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write Groovy code for Jenkins Pipeline, that will pull 3 Docker images from some repo in DockerHub, and then build a container from each image.

What I have tried so far:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Pull Images') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker pull dummy/new-repo:image1'
                sh 'docker pull dummy/new-repo:image2'
                sh 'docker pull dummy/new-repo:image3'
                
            }
        }
        stage('Build Containers') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build dummy/new-repo:image1'
            sh 'docker build dummy/new-repo:image2'
            sh 'docker build dummy/new-repo:image3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails with error in logs: ERROR: unable to prepare context: path "dummy/new-repo:image1" not found.

What am I doing wrong?